# Expected number of collisions when throwing colored balls into bins

Tags: balls-in-bins

Assume $b$ black balls and $w$ white balls. Throw them randomly and uniformly into $m$ bins.
What is the expected number of collisions between black and white balls:
(a) in each bin, 
(b) in all bins.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also: if a bin contains one white ball and two black balls, is that one collision or two?

Comment: If a bin contains one white ball and two black balls, then the number of collisions is $2$.

Comment: I am thinking the following: $\frac{w}{m}  \frac{b}{m}$ for the case of each bin and $\frac{wb}{m}$ for all the bins collectively.

Comment: For $b$ you can use linearity with the answer from $a$.  If there are four black balls in a bin is that six collisions?

Comment: What is a collision? Is the number of collisions just the number of equally-colored balls in a bin minus one (i.e., 1 is no collision, 2 is 1 collision, ..., 42 is 41 collisions)?

Comment: Your answer in the comment is correct.  Can you justify it?  Think linearity.

Comment: If there are $4$ black balls and one white, then the number of collisions is $4$.

Answer (score 1):

By assuming $m$ bins, the probability of any two balls of different color to collide is:

$$\frac{1}{m}.$$

We expect $\frac{w}{m}$ and $\frac{b}{m}$ of white and black balls, repsectively, in each bin. 
Therefore, the expected number $X$ of collisions in each bin is: $$E[X]=\frac{w \: b}{m^2}.$$
The expected number of collisions $Y$ in all bins is:
$$E[Y] = E[X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_m].$$

Using linearity of expectation, 
$$E[Y] = E[X_1] +E[X_2]+\ldots+E[X_m] = \sum_{j=1}^{m} E[X_j] = m \frac{w \: b}{m^2} =  \frac{w \: b}{m}.$$